# COLORREF as RGB or hexadecimal

Tags: c++, winapi, macros, rgb, getpixel

I have my current code that reads the `GetPixel` from the current cursor position but the return value is just some insane value by `COLORREF` and I want it to be in `RGB`. I looked into Microsoft Reference and I found `RGB` Macro

```
COLORREF RGB(
   BYTE byRed,
   BYTE byGreen,
   BYTE byBlue
);
```

and my question is how should I use the return from `GetPixel` into this `RGB` function and then print the value?
Current code:

```
include <Windows.h>
include <wingdi.h> 
include <iostream>
pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")

  int main() {
    while (true) {

      HDC hDC;
      hDC = GetDC(NULL);
      POINT p;
      GetCursorPos( & p);
      int cx = p.x;
      int cy = p.y;
      std::cout << GetPixel(hDC,cx,cy) << std::endl;
      Sleep(5);

    }

  }
```

Comment: The manual says "To create a COLORREF color value, use the RGB macro. To extract the individual values for the red, green, and blue components of a color value, use the [GetRValue, GetGValue, and GetBValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx) macros, respectively."

Comment: Insane, is that a technical term? PS nice infinite resource leak.

Comment: Ops forgot to release dc, damn you wrote faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetPixel()` function returns a `COLORREF` which you can convert to a `RGB` value like this:

```
COLORREF color = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
RGBTRIPLE rgb;

rgb.rgbtRed = GetRValue(color);
rgb.rgbtGreen = GetGValue(color);
rgb.rgbtBlue = GetBValue(color);
```

Comment: `[Error] 'RGB' was not declared in this scope` `Expected ';' before 'rgb'`

Comment: @MatthewMackday - I updated my answer. There is no structure named RGB but you can use `RGBTRIPLE` instead or simply uses a variable for each color e.g `BYTE red = GetRValue(color);` and so on.

Comment: and If I want to check if the 3 colors match like 255,61,205 I would just do conditional? `if(red == 255){if(green == 61)}if(blue==205){//the code to run here}`

Comment: @MatthewMackday - Yes that would work i.e `if(red == 255 && green == 61 && blue == 205) { // code }`

Comment: Or, do a single comparison on the `color` value itself instead of breaking it up into its individual components, eg: `if (color == RGB(255,61,205)) ...`

Comment: Trivial question: Your example seems right, but why does [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getrvalue) say `GetRValue` returns nothing? (MSDN describes it as `void GetRValue(rgb);`). `GetRValue`, etc. are just macros so I'm not sure if MSDN's description is correct.

Comment: @starriet주녕차 - This is because `GetRValue()` is a macro and not a function, which does not have a return value, instead it just tells the compiler to do a replacement. So this `rgb.rgbtRed = GetRValue(0xffffff);` will get replaced to `rgb.rgbtRed = 0xff;`.